# Android widget adding startapp ads

Tags: java, android

Does some one know how to add STARTAPP ads to widget app
This code does not work for the OnUpdate method 
AndroidSDKProvider.initSDK(this);

This must be added to OnCreate methode but my widget class has not OnCreate method
So how do i do that?
I don't even know if it is possible to add ads to widget?

Comment: please rephrase you question. its very difficult to understand. Also add your code and tell where the error is or what all u have tried out till now.

Answer (score 0):

You should call it on

onEnabled() function or on onUpdated().

Startapp has no ads, just launcher-shortcut outside the context of the widgets/application,
meaning it is possible to show 'ads' inside widets